# Troubleshoot SysV slow shutdown

Tags: shutdown, suse, sysvinit

The shutdown completes eventually but takes 7-8 min to finish. The OS is sles11. So I wonder is there anyway that I can add debug script to print any running processes and ask sysV init to execute it at the last stage of shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Script /etc/init.d/local.halt is executed when system shutdown. So put debug code to this file.